# Можно ли подключить mysql к Visual Studio чтобы не заходя в браузер отправлять данные?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

Стало интересно, можно ли подключить mysql к Visual Studio чтобы не заходя в браузер отправлять данные? Например пишу я статью, хочу запостить на сайт, но например если сайт без админки, долго заходить на хостинг, а оттуда в phpmyadmin. Возможно ли подключить форму к mysql и прямо с неё отправлять данные?
Заранее спасибо всем!

Comment: Окошко `Server Explorer` не пробовали открывать?

Comment: Понадобится установить адаптер для .NET, по умолчанию студия умеет работать только с продуктами MS. А дальше как с любой другой БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Поставить адаптер что бы работать с базой которая не является MSSQL
2. Написать простенький PHP скрипт который будет отлавливать твои пост/гет запросы и взаимодействовать с БД. Что-то вроде

   ```
   $servername = "localhost";
   $dbname = "_arealitydb";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $queryDebug = false;

   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   function queryExec($query) { 
       if ( $GLOBALS["queryDebug"]) 
       {
           echo $query + "<br>";
       }

       $conn = $GLOBALS["conn"];

       $sql = $query;
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

       if (!$result) 
       {
           die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
       }

       return $result;
   }

   function getFirstCellValueFromQuery($query)
   {
       return queryExec($query) -> fetch_array()[0];
   }
   function printJsonFromQuery($query)
   {
       $result = queryExec($query);

       $rows = array();
       while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $rows[] = $r;
       }
       print json_encode($rows);
   }
   ```

для взаимодействия с бд

и что-то вроде:

```
if ( isset($_GET['queryToExecute']) ) {
    $query =  $_GET['queryToExecute'];
    queryExec($query);
}
```

Ну а дальше достаточно просто сделать запрос на страницу с параметром

`http://localhost/sqlExecutor.php?queryToExecute=SomeQueryText`

***Первый вариант лучше, но второй так же сработает.***